# Windows 10 sandbox process to launch 2 instances

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an application, which restricts multi-instance launch. I would like to launch it let's say twice at the same time. Is there any software that can sandbox the app process so it has no access to check if it is already running?

Comment: As for now I just created a virtual machine, and start second instance in it. It works, but this solution is not resource-effective